# How to get an entry from a user?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This is the wholeof my code:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import os

def bowlingspeedcalc ():
        entry = float(mEntry)
        if type(entry) == float:
            speed = 0.01890*3600/entry

            if speed >165:
                Label1 = tk.Label (str(speed) + " kph !!! You don't bowl that fast!!!o_0 ").place (x = 50,y = 50)                             

            elif speed >=140:
                Label2 = tk.Label ("You are a fast bowler,you bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour").place (x = 50,y = 50) 

            elif speed >= 130:
                Label3 = tk.Label ("You are a fast-medium bowler,you bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour").place (x = 50,y = 50)

            elif speed >= 120:
                Label4 = tk.Label ("You are a medium-fast bowler,you bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour").place (x = 50,y = 50)

            elif speed >= 105:
                Label5 = tk.Label ("You are a medium pace bowler,you bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour").place (x = 50,y = 50)

            elif speed < 105 and speed > 60:
                Label6 = tk.Label ("You are a spin bowler,you bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour").place (x = 50,y = 50)

            elif speed <= 60:
                Label7 = tk.Label ("You bowl at: " + str(speed) + " kilometers per hour; you bowl like my grandma!!!").place (x = 50,y = 50)

def forget_page ():
    widgets = [mlabel1,mlabel2,mlabel3,mEntry,mButton]
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.place_forget ()
    bowlingspeedcalc ()


    mGui = tk.Tk()
    mGui.geometry("300x300")
    mGui.title("YourBowlingSpeed")
    mlabel1 = tk.Label (text = "How much time does your ball take to cover the")
    mlabel2 = tk.Label (text = "20m/22yrds ,from the release to crossing ")
    mlabel3 = tk.Label (text = "the stumps?")
    mlabel1.place (x = 20,y = 5)
    mlabel2.place (x = 17,y = 22)
    mlabel3.place (x = 130,y = 39)
    mEntry = tk.Entry()
    mEntry.place (x = 115,y = 56)
    mButton = tk.Button (text = "Calculate",command = forget_page)
    mButton.place (x = 125, y = 73)
    mGui.mainloop()
```

This is my code i know what the problem is but i don't know how to solve it . a command goes to bowlingspeedcalc () and there the probem starts nohing comes on .Thats because mEntry can't be converted to a float but is there a way i can convert mEntry to a the float value the user enters? Any help would me appreciated !

This is the error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python33\Projects\YourBowlingSpeed.py", line 36, in forget_page

bowlingspeedcalc ()
File "C:\Python33\Projects\YourBowlingSpeed.py", line 7, in bowlingspeedcalc
entry = float(mEntry)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: but i dont want to convert it into a str()?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mEntry.get()` to obtain the text provided by the user.  So, the first line of `bowlingspeedcalc` should be:

```
entry= float(mEntry.get())
```

Also, I'm not sure how you are making `mEntry` visible to `bowlingspeedcalc`.  It could be formatting of your post.  Or you could be in need of a `global`.

Comment: @ShahidIqbal  Added a bit more detail.  Hope it's clearer.  Please note that I'm answering your specific question "is there a way i can convert mEntry to a the float value the user enters?".  If the problem is different, or you encountered a new one, please post a new question and be specific.

Comment: oh i tried differently and it works do you see an error in my labels in myif elif statements because it now shows me an error in my labels:((((

Comment: @ShahidIqbal  Very glad to hear that, Shahid.